# Extract files from a Nokia backup

Tags: windows, nokia-pc-suite

Is there a way to access the files, contacts and calendar items contained in a Nokia PC Suite backup without actually having a phone to connect? i.e. some program or file format details that would allow me to read this on a Windows PC.

Even an SDK would be fine.

Details:

- PC Suite 7.1
- Nokia E65
- backup extension is **.nbu**

Surely the point of a backup is to be able to access the data if the phone is lost/broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Noki](http://www.nokisoft.com/)

> Noki is a utility to explore and extract Phone book, Text message, MMS, Calendar, Memo, Email,  Bookmark and other user files from the backup file of Nokia phone (using  Nokia PC Suite).